# django bootstrap navbar dropdown elements not coming on other url while using same base.html

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

I am new to django and creating one app. I have create two mode on is master and other is details.
While using a bootstrap nav bar drop down on a single base.html i am able to get master records in drop down while i switch to different page when clicked any drop down element i didn't get drop down element. I am extending base.html in both the master as well as detail page. Please help with any option

**dropdown working**
http://127.0.0.1:8000/environment/

**dropdown not working**
http://127.0.0.1:8000/environment/env_name

**base.html**

```
 <!-- menu buttons -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topNavBar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown" >
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true"></span> Environment
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                              {% for envmaster in all_envmaster %}
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'environment:detail' envmaster.env_name %}">{{ envmaster.env_name }}</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                              {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        <!--<a href="{% url 'environment:index' %}">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Environment
                        </a>-->
                    </li>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Details
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

**detail.html**

```
<!-- Loads the path to your static files -->

{% extends 'environment/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Environment Details{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <!--<img src="{{ envmaster.env_name }}" style="width: 250px;"><br>-->

    <h3>{{ envmaster.env_name }}</h3>

    {% if error_message %}
        <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
    {% endif %}

        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for envdetail in envmaster.envdetail_set.all %}
        <li>{{ envdetail.env_component }} - {{ envdetail.component_class }} - {{ envdetail.value_1 }}</li><br>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**index.html**

```
<!-- Loads the path to your static files -->

{% extends 'environment/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Environment Details{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    {% if all_envmaster %}
        <h3>Here are all Environment:</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for envmaster in all_envmaster %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'environment:detail' envmaster.env_name %}">{{ envmaster.env_name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <h3>You don't have any Environment</h3>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Envmaster(models.Model):
    env_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=256)
    env_type = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    env_owner = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    cur_release = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ENVMASTER'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('environment:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.env_name


class Envdetail(models.Model):
    env_name = models.ForeignKey(Envmaster,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    env_component = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    component_class = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    value_1 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    value_2 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    value_3 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    additional_info = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ENVDETAIL'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.env_component
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Envmaster


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'environment/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_envmaster'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Envmaster.objects.all()


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Envmaster
    template_name = 'environment/detail.html'
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),

    #/environment/env_name/
    re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[\w\-]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

Comment: Please update your question by adding formatted code instead of screenshots of your code. Read through [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a templates folder inside src folder you created and add create base.html inside that folder.

[image]

Than add in in you setting.py inside [Templates] add the location of the templates folder like this

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

and than just extend you html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

While going through different posts and trying I have created a context file at app level so that once the class object is initialized it should retain the values within the navigation bar

```
from .models import Envmaster

def show_env_menu(context):
   env_menu = Envmaster.onjects.all()
   return {'env_menu': env_menu}
```